# .NET Dispatcher class missing (System.Windows.Threading)

Tags: .net, dispatcher

I read about the `Dispatcher` class in .NET. But curiously the `System.Windows.Threading` namespace does not exist in my case ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx)). Do I get something wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your framework version and references (you need a reference to WindowsBase and framework version 3+ or Silverlight)

Answer (score 1):

What type of project is it?
It might be because you are writing a "Class Library".
Check the "Output type:" on the application tab of the project properties.

It is not intuitive to me but it seems "using System.Threading;" in a "Class Library" does not give access to the Dispatcher type when the same using statement placed in a console or wpf project do.

Comment: Check the answer.  You need to add a reference to WindowsBase to your project to have access to the System.Threading namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Add Reference WindowsBase, then add

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

so you will be able to use code like:

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; set; }
```

screenshot:
[image]